# Why can't I download a file when the server returns HTTP 302 Found using HttpClient in C#?

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-core-3.1, http-status-code-302

I have issues downloading a file which is eventually returned after a 302.

Suppose I have a URL like this: https://myhost/export/myfile.php. When I navigate to this URL in my browser, the file downloads.

However, I want to download the file using C#.

Here's what I've tried, using `HttpClient`, which doesn't work:

```
var uri = "https://myhost/export/myfile.php";
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        /// it never reach here because 302 is not sucess status code
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `WebClient`:

```
var url = "https://myhost/export/myfile.php";
using (var webclient = new WebClient())
{
    var response = await _webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url); // throws an exception regarding HTTP status being 302 Found
    string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
}
```

How can I download a file which is returned after redirects?

---------Problem solved ------------
After @Ermiya Eskandary 's support, I finally found the root cause. This request missing a header name 'Cookie' that needed for authentication (which I misunderstanding it with cookie => wrong configuration for request). Thank god send this man to help me out.

Comment: What is the status code after `var response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);` - are you **100% sure** it is 302?

Comment: Whats the URL you are being redirected to? For .NET Core 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 it will not follow a redirect from a HTTPS to HTTP - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-5.0

Comment: Yes, it's 302 and i'm using netcore 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTTP response with status code [302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) indicates that the requested information is located at the URI specified in the `Location` header of the response (a redirect essentially).

Considering you have set `HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect`, the handler will automatically follow HTTP redirections headers until you reach a response that doesn't have a status code indicating a redirection.

I also don't suspect that the server is redirecting you more than 50 times, which is the default value for [`HttpClientHandler.MaxAutomaticRedirections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxautomaticredirections?view=net-5.0) so that only leaves one thing.

Either the server is actually returning a failing status code for whatever reason once the response is complete or if it isn't, an *important* note to be aware of is that unless you are using the .NET Framework (and not .NET Core etc.), [**`HttpClient` will not follow redirections from a secure HTTPS endpoint to an insecure HTTP endpoint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-5.0).

You cannot override automatic redirection dis-allowing HTTPS -> HTTP for security reasons however if you **must**, parse the `Location` header yourself until the redirection is complete.

This should work:

```
var uri = "https://myhost/export/myfile.php";

var initialRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URI);

initialRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=...");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(initialRequestMessage);

    while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
    {
        Uri redirectedUri = response.Headers.Location;
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, redirectedUri);
        response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }

    // response is successful or unsuccessful but will not be a redirect
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: still didn't solve my issue yet, the 'response.Headers.Location' have same uri with the origin url. But I'm really impressed with your answer, thanks for your help man.

Comment: @TôĐôngHồ Then is the resource just redirecting to itself constantly? Does it actually end up anywhere? Can you download it from the browser? This sounds like a server issue.

Comment: I put the link on the browser and hit enter, it download immediately. When i use postman, it return 302 also. But when I turn on 'Automatically follow redirects' settings, it get the response smoothly. (x_x)

Comment: Can you share the link at all, please? If it returns a 302, the code above will 100% work unless the server requires other headers/user agent. The above code will work (considering you haven't done `handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;`) - the above code should replace all of your code.

Comment: @TôĐôngHồ The above code will either get stuck in an infinite loop or eventually exit the while loop - does it exit the while loop? Try the updated answer and let me know the output